# voltage-controlled switches "SW" in LTspice

Tags: ltspice, spice

I've simulated the following circuit. the confusion is that why the fall and rise times of turning on and off are such that big? how to make it more ideal? (in the range of nanoseconds)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you tell the simulator to use such small (nanosecond) timesteps? If you didn't, the simulator will **guess** what it needs to use and that might not be what you want. Realize that calculating with nano second accuracy in a 50 ms simulation will result in 50 ms / 1 ns = 50 million points, that might result in you waiting for results to appear. I **ALWAYS** set a maximum timestep when doing a transient simulation, such that I get at least 1000 points.

Comment: https://www.ti.com/product/CD4053B has a  Bandwidth  20 MHz,
https://www.ti.com/product/CD4066B has a  Bandwidth  40 MHz, i also recently started using simulators, but ..., breadboarding or vero board is best. if you have a scope.

Comment: You haven't told us where those node references are connected.

Comment: It's not a bad habit to form to use negative hysteresis, even if small, because zero or strictly positive `vh` makes the VCSW to switch abruptly between `Ron` and `Roff`. Discontinuities are not SPICE's best friend. In this case, if you want a zero crossing, it's better to use the `[Digital]` gates, with proper `ref`, or `vt, vh` for `schmitt` gates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the simulation control panel set Maximum Timestep to 10n

Your .tran card should look like

```
.tran 0 0.05 0 10n
```

Btw you don't need the Roff, Vt and Vh parameters to sw.  Your settings are similar to the defaults.  And the Ron could be 1u or 1m, given the max 3A that will flow through the resistor. (Note the default Ron 1R so that would not work)

Comment: if it's related to max timestep, why are the fall and rise times of a pulse voltage source adjusted as 1ns is accurately 1ns while the max timestep is not defined at all?

Comment: @Kamran The simulator adds special timepoints (called "breakpoints") at each transition point for all PULSE and PWL sources.  It doesn't do the same for the SINE source so you need to force it yourself for finer timepoint resolution.